# How to call specific method with same name

Tags: java

I have these two methods:

```
public void method(final String param1, final Object... param2);

public void method(final String param1, final String param2, final Object... param3);
```

If I call the first method this way:

```
method(new String(), new String(), new String());
```

I'll get the second method because the parameters match perfectly with it. If I put the last two strings in a list I already can call the first one, but I want to know if there is another better way to do it.

Comment: „ but I want to know if there is another better way to do it.“ - rename one?

Comment: "How do you call a specific method with the same name?" - You simply provide the correct signature based on the expected arguments. In Java, methods are allowed to have the same name provided they have unique function signatures. It sounds like you already know how to call one versus the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
method(new String(), (Object) new String(), new String());
```

calls the first method.

This works because the second method doesn't accept `Object` as the second parameter, but the first one does.

It's besides the point, but I can't not point out that this should really be:

```
method("", (Object) "", "");
```

which does basically the same thing, but doesn't create pointless `String` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the last parameter as an `Object[]`:

```
method("A", "B", new Object[]{"C"});
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/ybi2x3).

Comment: Would you really consider this a "better way to do it" ? The OP appears to already know how to call one method versus the other.

Comment: @h0r53 I'm not sure OP does know how.

Comment: BTW this will call the same method as will `method("A", "B", "C");` - [online demo](https://ideone.com/vxqdWs)